# Create a Excel Macro to copy formulas down across variable/unknown number of columns?

Tags: excel, formulas, vba

I would like to create a single macro in excel that I can reuse on other sheets to 
copy the formulas down from from B4:B? down to Row number X.

I will be pasting various rows of data into Column A of several different worksheets. I will have a button on each sheet that I'd like to label "Copy Formulas". I have written formulas to parse out the text into anywhere from 3 to 250 columns, depending on the sheet. I would like the macro to highlight from B4 to Selection.End(xlToRight) then copy that selection down until the last row of data in column A.

I was thinking of something like this but I keep getting an error on line 6.

```
    Dim strCurrentSheet As String
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim LastCol As Integer
    LastRow = Range("A4").End(xlDown).Row
    LastCol = Range("B4").End(xlToRight).Column
    Range(Cells(4, 2), Cells(4, LastCol)).AutoFill _ 
    Destination:=Range(Cells(5, 2), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a VBA macro to do so, consider using Excel tables (Insert->Table) from the start - it has this functionality more or less build in:

If you enter a formula an empty column in a table (or an adjacent column next to it), Excel will automatically apply the formula to all rows. And if you add/copy data at any point, it will automatically expand the table and therefore also apply the formulas in all columns!

Answer (score 0):

... I didn't test this code too much, but this should at least give you a good starting point and set you on your way:

```
Sub test()

  ' Get the last row and column on the sheet - store them in the variables
  Dim LastRow As Integer
  Dim LastCol As Integer
  LastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
  LastCol = Range("B4").End(xlToRight).Column

  ' Copy cells B4:B[LastCol]  to  cells B4:[LastRow][LastCol]
  Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(2, LastCol)).AutoFill _
         Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(LastRow, LastCol))

End Sub
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Not sure about the Copy Cells part - Are the 2,4 examples you gave in the code transposed? I have updated my question above with some code and I am getting an error on the last line.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Dim colABottom As Range
    Set colABottom = Range("A1").End(xlDown)

    Dim colEnd As Range
    Set colEnd = Range("A1").End(xlToRight)

    Dim lColStart As Long
    lColStart = 2
    Dim lColEnd As Long
    lColEnd = colEnd.Column

    Dim lRowStart As Long
    lRowStart = 1
    Dim lRowEnd As Long
    lRowEnd = colABottom.Row

    Dim startRange As Range
    Set startRange = Range("B1")

    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Set sourceRange = Range(startRange, startRange.End(xlToRight))

    Dim destinationFillRange As Range
    Set destinationFillRange = Range(Cells(lRowStart, lColStart), Cells(lRowEnd, lColEnd))

    sourceRange.AutoFill Destination:=destinationFillRange
```